# How to set permission in a XPS Document?

Tags: c#, .net, xps, xpsdocument

I need to secure a XPS Document in C#, but I dont find any Library, please help me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "secure an XPS document".

- If you mean adding a signature so the reader can verify that the document was generated by you, I'd suggest looking at [System.Windows.Xps.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.aspx).
- If you mean encrypting a document to restrict who can view it's contents, I'd suggest looking at [System.IO.Packaging.EncryptedPackageEnvelope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.encryptedpackageenvelope.aspx)